# MySQL: counting records of multiple parent/children structures in the same query

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm implementing a forum system. I need to return a condensed list of records that includes:

- The last available question of a **lang/category** combination.
- It must be grouped by: lang (this is the main language of the forum, e.g.: es, en, pt) and id_forum_cat (there are 4 numeric categories).
- I need to display the count of the total topics inside the **lang/category** combination, and the sum of the replies that are inside the topics that belong to each **lang/category** combination. *(here's where my current issue is)*

My query is correctly grouping the records by **lang/category**, and the `total_topics` count is also correct, but the `total_replies` is not working as it should. `total_replies` should be the sum of the replies that are inside the topics that belong to each **lang/category** combination. This is my current query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total_topics
FROM (
    SELECT
    forum.id_forum_cat AS id_forum_cat,
    forum.lang AS lang,
    forum.id_forum AS id_forum,
    forum.date_insert AS date_insert,
    forum.question AS question,
    forum.description AS description,
    forum_cat.name AS cat,
    COUNT(forum_reply.id_forum_reply) AS total_replies
    FROM forum
    LEFT JOIN forum_reply ON forum_reply.id_forum = forum.id_forum
    JOIN forum_cat ON forum_cat.id_forum_cat = forum.id_forum_cat
    GROUP BY id_forum
    ORDER BY forum.date_insert DESC
) AS tmp_forum GROUP BY lang, id_forum_cat
```

I've set a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d11418/1) with some data:

- There are 4 forums.
- 3 of those forums belong to the **1/en** combination.
- 1 of those forums belong to the **2/en** combination.
- There are 3 replies.
- 2 of those replies belong to the 1st forum (which belongs to the **1/en** combination).
- 1 of those replies belongs to the 2nd forum (which also belongs to the **1/en** combination).

Having said that, the **1/en** combination should return `3` in the `total_replies` column. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you used a lazy short cut, if you ha full_group_b<Y enabled this would immediately given an error

You have to use [aggregation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) for all  for all columns that are not in the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    id_forum_cat
    ,lang
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(id_forum) id_forum
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(date_insert) date_insert
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(question) question
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(description) description
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(cat) cat
    ,SUM(total_replies)
    , COUNT(*) AS total_topics
FROM (
    SELECT
    forum.id_forum_cat AS id_forum_cat,
    forum.lang AS lang,
    forum.id_forum AS id_forum,
    forum.date_insert AS date_insert,
    forum.question AS question,
    forum.description AS description,
    forum_cat.name AS cat,
    COUNT(forum_reply.id_forum_reply) AS total_replies
    FROM forum
    LEFT JOIN forum_reply ON forum_reply.id_forum = forum.id_forum
    JOIN forum_cat ON forum_cat.id_forum_cat = forum.id_forum_cat
    GROUP BY id_forum
    ORDER BY forum.date_insert DESC
) AS tmp_forum GROUP BY lang, id_forum_cat
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d11418/5

```
id_forum_cat    lang    id_forum    date_insert     question    description     cat     SUM(total_replies)  total_topics
1   en  3,2,1   2020-10-27 18:21:48,2020-10-27 18:13:29,2020-10-27 09:53:26     This is my third question! Right?,This is my second question. Right?,First! How do you say horse in spanish?    Im adding a third question for count purposes.,Im adding a second question for count purposes.,This is the first question of the first category. I need how to say horse in spanish in a conversation.  general,general,general     3   3
2   en  4   2020-10-27 19:17:01     First question in other category?   This is the first question of the second category.  grammar     0   1
```

Comment: just noticed, the query is basically returning all the forums dates (18:21:48,2020-10-27 18:13:29,2020-10-27 09:53:26) and all the data that belongs to each combination, it should be just the most recent record. The COUNT and SUM work alright, but the GROUP_CONCATS are unnecessary as per the first requirement.

Comment: As i explained, when You GROUP BY all columns that are not in the GROUP BY itself, must have a aggregation function, every thing else, works only in old mysql Versions and i still don't know why, it should work. but feel free to do what you want.